# Problem with image and frame bordering in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm currently making a personal project of an application using customtkinter library but I encountered a problem when I set a background image then try to add another widget, It creates a small border between the frame and the background image.

this is how my code currently looks

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter


root=ctk.CTk()
root.geometry('600x400')


background=ctk.CTkImage(Image.open(r'Image.png'),size=(1920,1080))


lab=ctk.CTkLabel(root,image=background,text='')
lab.pack()

Fr=ctk.CTkFrame(lab,corner_radius=15,fg_color='green')
Fr.place(rely=0.5,relx=0.5,anchor=tkinter.CENTER)


root.mainloop()
```

I put the frame inside the label which contains the background image but that resulted in the previous error stated above. I tried to change the master to root but that resulted in the same outcome. When I try to make the background a plain color without using the image parameter it works fine.